# Rails 4: Solr throwing JavaMissing error, but Java is installed

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, solr

I restarted my Rails 4 VPS and Solr was obviously also shutdown. I am now trying to startup Solr but when I run the following `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:203:in `ensure_java_installed'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:27:in `initialize'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:37:in `new'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:37:in `server'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The weird thing is that Java is installed:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm not sure what might be causing this behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: how sunspot determines if Java is installed: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/v2.1.1/sunspot_solr/lib/sunspot/solr/java.rb#L9

Comment: Running that from the Rails console returns nil :\ that might be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to `PATH` the folder where `java` is, like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/java/bin
```

so that java could be callable from everywhere without specifying the folder.

Launching this before calling rake solved the problem for me.