# Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Trying to start Solr with sunspot but having an issue with the Java Runtime Environment by getting this error.

```
root@oktobTest:~# dokku run oktob bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:203:in `ensure_java_installed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:27:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:38:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:38:in `server'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Solar is up and running on the remote server.

Java is installed

```
root@oktobTest:~# which java
/usr/bin/java
```

And this is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

```
root@oktobTest:~# sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1073      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1073      manual mode
```

I edited `/etc/profile` file to export the path inspired by discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970123/sunspot-solr-not-starting-with-you-need-a-java-runtime-environment-to-run-the-s) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534939/rails-4-solr-throwing-javamissing-error-but-java-is-installed) and [javaandme](http://javaandme.com/)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

I'm not sure about the path above is it correct or not.

`config/sunspot.xml` file

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

Answer (score 3):

To me, reinstallation JDK(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) fixes the problem that happened during the first use of solr in El Capitan

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. When running the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start -t

** Invoke sunspot:solr:start (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:start
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
```

By using this command

```
$ bundle exec rake --execute 'puts which java'
```

I am getting '/usr/bin/java'.

But by the following command

```
$ java --version -> 'No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I am using Mac OSX and it prompted a message and clicking on more info it goes to:

```
oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

So I installed JDK 8 from the link:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

for mac OSX

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-macosx-x64.dmg

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

After that Solr server run successfully :) .

**In your case you have to reinstall the JDK from the above link to make it work**

You have openJDK runtime environment. Switch to Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, to make Solr work. Read this ([difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360011/technically-what-is-the-main-difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk#comment27153592_17364418))

Run the Solr server background by

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start -t

Successfully started Solr ...
```

Stop Solr server:

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop -t
```

Start solr server in the foreground:

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run -t
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some topics about this problem. If you are sure that Java on the server is fine, please try to paste in configuration file (config/sunspot.yml) for the relevant environment this line "solr_home: solr" and start solr server by "RAILS_ENV=[your_env] bundle exec sunspot:solr:start"

Comment: I did `solr_home: solr` but no success, and when I include `RAILS_ENV=production` inside the command I recieve `App oktob RAILS_ENV=production does not exist`

Comment: Sorry, but I think there is a problem with your machine/hosting, as you can see you can't even start simple command. Where are you hosted and which distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using DigitalOcean with Ubuntu and Rails deployed with Dokku, but everything is working and the Demo app is running at 46.101.47.185 and  Solor at http://46.101.47.185:8983/solr/#/

Comment: Sure, so maybe this tutorial would by helpful: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Yes I have used this article as my main source.